# How to set bitrate limit in FFMPEG

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-streaming, transcoding

How can I limit bitrate of a transcoding video in FFMPEG to keep it under a limit value?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use this code

```
ffmpeg -i myfile.avi -b 4000k -minrate 4000k -maxrate 4000k -bufsize 1835k out.m2v
```

Comment: Thank you! exactly I needed `minrate` and `maxrate`

Comment: -b set video and audio's average bit rate per second

Comment: Note: "maxrate integer (encoding,audio,video) - Set max bitrate tolerance (in bits/s). Requires bufsize to be set." - see also https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Limiting%20the%20output%20bitrate

Answer (score 7):

Read the documentation here: http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#Description

> To set the video bitrate of the output file to 64 kbit/s:

```
 ffmpeg -i input.avi -b:v 64k -bufsize 64k output.avi
```